# KeySet does not exist while running the wcf service

Tags: wcf, certificate

I have some wcf services and which are using some certificates for security reasons.
I have installed the services on my machine but when I am trying to run these services an error is occurring that `KeySet` does not exist.

I searched on internet but couldn't find a solution.
Can anyone please give me an idea what is missing or how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you include the exception/error message you're recieving. Does the service work without the certificate?

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602345/cryptographicexception-keyset-does-not-exist-but-only-through-wcf

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps

**Start -> Run -> MMC
File -> Add/Remove Snapin
Add the Certificates Snap In
Select Computer Account, then hit next
Select Local Computer, then click Finish
navigate to Certificates> Personal -> Certificates
Right click on your certificate -> All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys
Set your private key settings here.**