# X509Certificate2 p12 is store required?

Tags: c#, x509certificate, private-key, x509certificate2

Question when running the following code:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\file.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
RSACryptoServiceProvider crypt = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
```

I get the following error: `Keyset does not exist`.

I have not added the certificate to a store, is this required to be able to access the private key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the [X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags.aspx) option to the last argument of the X509Certificate2 constructor. Otherwise, when it loads the p12 file, it will not load the private key. Specifically:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\file.p12", "password",    
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
RSACryptoServiceProvider crypt = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
```

If that fails, it may be a file permission issue on where the key is stored. See [X509Certificate - Keyset does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392268/x509certificate-keyset-does-not-exist) for an explanation and example.

Comment: @Rutger I added an additional check in the answer.

Comment: I have not added the certificate to a store, is this required?

Comment: @Rutger The code is not adding to a certificate store but it is storing the private key in the key store (related but different concept). The issue maybe access to the key store.

Comment: It was indeed an access issue with the key store.