# "Invalid provider type specified" CryptographicException when trying to load private key of certificate

Tags: c#, windows, certificate, mmc, certificate-store

I'm trying to read the private key of a certificate which has been shared with me by a third-party service provider, so I can use it to encrypt some XML before sending it to them over the wire. I'm doing so programmatically in C#, but I think this is a permissions or misconfiguration issue, so I'll focus on the facts which seem to be most relevant:

- I don't think this issue is code-related; my code works on other computers, and the issue affects sample code from Microsoft.
- The certificate was provided as a PFX file and is just for test purposes, so it also includes a dummy certification authority.
- Using MMC.exe, I can import the certificate into the personal store for the local machine, before granting permissions on the private key to all relevant accounts, and dragging and dropping the certification authority into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities.
- Using C#, I can load the certificate (identified by its thumbprint) and verify that it has a private key using `X509Certificate2.HasPrivateKey`. However, trying to read the key causes an error. In .NET a `CryptographicException` is thrown with the message "Invalid provider type specified" upon trying to access the property `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey`. In Win32, calling the method `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey` returns the equivalent HRESULT, `NTE_BAD_PROV_TYPE`.
- This is the same exception which also occurs when using two of Microsoft's own code samples to read the private key of the certificate.
- Installing the same certificate in the equivalent store for the current user, instead of the local machine, allows the private key to be successfully loaded.
- I'm on Windows 8.1 with local administrator rights, and I've tried running my code in both normal and elevated modes. Colleagues on Windows 7 and Windows 8 have been able to load the key from the local machine store for the same certificate.
- I can successfully read the private key of the self-signed IIS test certificate, which is in the same store location.
- I am already targeting .NET 4.5 (this error has been reported with some older versions of the framework).
- I don't think this is a problem with certificate templates, because I would expect that to affect both the local machine and current-user stores equally?

Unlike my colleagues, I have made multiple previous attempts to uninstall and re-install the certificate in various ways, including via IIS Manager and also including an older certificate from the same issuer. I can't see any traces of old or duplicate certificates in MMC. However, I do have many private key files of identical size which, based on the last-write time, must have been left behind after my various installation attempts. These are found at the following locations, for the local machine and current user stores respectively:

c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

c:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-[rest of user ID]

So, can anyone please advise whether:

- It's a good idea to uninstall the certificate using MMC, delete all those files which look like orphaned private keys, and then re-install the certificate and try again?
- There any other files which I should try to manually delete?
- There's anything else I should try?

UPDATE - Added a code sample showing an attempt to read a private key:

```
static void Main()
{
    // Exception occurs when trying to read the private key after loading certificate from here:
    X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    // Exception does not occur if certificate was installed to, and loaded from, here:
    //X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

    X509Certificate2Collection collection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
    X509Certificate2Collection fcollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
    X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Test Certificate Select", "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate", X509SelectionFlag.MultiSelection);
    Console.WriteLine("Number of certificates: {0}{1}", scollection.Count, Environment.NewLine);

    foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in scollection)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Private Key: {0}", x509.HasPrivateKey ? x509.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(false) : "[N/A]");
            x509.Reset();
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    store.Close();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you post the relevant code...

Comment: @DavidW Please see above for the code sample, as you suggested - however, I think this is almost certainly an issue with a misconfigured certificate or corrupted file, rather than a coding mistake.

Comment: Hmm...awfully tough to diagnose something like this if it isn't programming-related, but I did a little snooping and found the following: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/12/22/invalid-provider-type-specified-error-when-accessing-x509certificate2-privatekey.aspx that sounds as thought it might be related (obscure Invalid Provider Type exc. reading private key)..

Comment: @DavidW Thanks David but I've already seen that article, and I've made sure that I'm targeting .NET 4.5.

Comment: Did you try to right click the certificate, select "manage private keys" and add yourself to the permission list in an explicit way?

Comment: @WiktorZychla Good idea, but yes - I tried granting permissions to the "Everyone" group for good measure.

Comment: Odd as it may sound, you might actually try firing up Process/File Monitor and let it run with your app...if there's a permissions issue on one of those keys, it'll show  up as an access denied and could point to the exact source...

Comment: @DavidW Good idea, thanks! No ACCESS DENIED appears in Process Monitor when trying to access the key of the dodgy certificate. I did prove the concept of your suggestion, though, by taking ownership of my IIS test certificate's key file and denying myself access. Process Monitor detected it, but the exception thrown is slightly different: "Keyset does not exist".

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, we never found a solution, and ended up getting a fresh system from the IT department. Good luck!

Comment: I got the same exception (System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
  HResult=0x80090014
  Message=Invalid provider type specified.) when debugging in VS2022 without "Run as administrator". Once I ran VS2022 as admin, the exception went away. No code change was needed.

Answer (score 58):

I had the same problem on Windows 8 and Server 2012/2012 R2 with two new certificates I recently received. On Windows 10, the problem no longer occurs (but that does not help me, as the code manipulating the certificate is used on a server). While the solution of Joe Strommen in principle works, the different private key model would require massive change to the code using the certificates. I find that a better solution is to convert the private key from CNG to RSA, as explained by Remy Blok [here](http://remyblok.tweakblogs.net/blog/11803/converting-certificate-to-use-csp-storage-provider-in-stead-of-cng-storage-provider).

Remy uses OpenSSL and two older tools to accomplish the private key conversion, we wanted to automate it and developed an OpenSSL-only solution. Given `MYCERT.pfx` with private key password `MYPWD` in CNG format, these are the steps to get a new `CONVERTED.pfx` with private key in RSA format and same password:

1. Extract public keys, full certificate chain:

```
OpenSSL pkcs12 -in "MYCERT.pfx" -nokeys -out "MYCERT.cer" -passin "pass:MYPWD"
```

2. Extract private key:

```
OpenSSL pkcs12 -in "MYCERT.pfx" -nocerts -out "MYCERT.pem" -passin "pass:MYPWD" -passout "pass:MYPWD"
```

3. Convert private key to RSA format:

```
OpenSSL rsa -inform PEM -in "MYCERT.pem" -out "MYCERT.rsa" -passin "pass:MYPWD" -passout "pass:MYPWD"
```

4. Merge public keys with RSA private key to new PFX:

```
OpenSSL pkcs12 -export -in "MYCERT.cer" -inkey "MYCERT.rsa" -out "CONVERTED.pfx" -passin "pass:MYPWD" -passout "pass:MYPWD"
```

If you load the converted pfx or import it in the Windows certificate store instead of the CNG format pfx, the problem goes away and the C# code does not need to change.

One additional gotcha that I encountered when automating this: we use long generated passwords for the private key and the password may contain `"`. For the OpenSSL command line, `"` characters inside the password must be escaped as `""`.

Comment: This solved my problem, wish I would have found this a couple hours ago!

Comment: I found similar instructions here: http://www.componentspace.com/Forums/ComponentSpace-Knowledge-Bases/Knowledge-Base-SAML-SSO-for-ASP.NET so it seems like this might have some merit.

Comment: @Berend, step 1 above created .cert file.  Step2  did not create .pem, there was no error displayed but it said, "pkcs12: Use -help for summary."
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @vkelman: OpenSSL does that when it encounters any unknown parameter. I guess it depends on the version. We're still using my tool for converting cng to rsa certificates, with OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015.

If the command line output does not give you a clue which part of the command line is deprecated, you might save yourself some time by simply using the archived 1.0.2d version. For Windows, archived versions can be found here: https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/

Comment: So this answer summarized is: "create a new pfx based on the old pfx" ? hmm

Comment: This saved my life, I was having issues with a certificate loaded in IIS for SAML/ADFS login response decryption.

Comment: How can one determine what format the private key in the PFX is in ?

Comment: another solution following this idea I simply imported the cert into my cert store and then exported it again with the private key and the problem went away.

Answer (score 43):

In my case, I was trying to use a self-signed certificate with PowerShell's New-SelfSignedCertificate command.  By default, it will generate a certificate using the CNG (Crypto-Next Generation) API instead of the older/classic crypto CAPI.  Some older pieces of code will have trouble with this; in my case it was an older version of the IdentityServer STS provider.

By adding this at the end of my New-SelfSignedCertificate command, I got past the issue:

**-KeySpec KeyExchange**

Reference on the switch for the powershell command:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps

Comment: this helped thanks.  i also need to ensure the user has access to the private key, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106011/system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-keyset-does-not-exist

Comment: Love you ! Thanks ;)

Comment: Exactly on spot, thank you! In fact, all options except `None` work for the `-KeySpec` paramater, for instance: `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "IssuedToName" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My" -KeySpec Signature`

Comment: Oh thank god, after so many hours. For anyone from the future that is in my situation of trying to make a local proxy for a website, your program may need to run as admin to access the private key + the cert may have to be in /Root instead of /My to be accepted

Comment: We had this problem with an app deployed to Azure App Services and this flag fixed it

Comment: thank you you have saved me so much frustration!

Answer (score 20):

Here is another reason that this can happen, 
this was a weird issue and after struggling for a day I solved the issue. 
As an experiment I changed permission for **"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys"** folder which holds private key data for certificates using Machine key store. When you change permission for this folder all privatekeys shows up as "Microsoft Software KSP provider" which is not the provider (in my case they are supposed to be " Microsoft RSA Schannel Cryptographic Provider").

**Solution: Reset permissions to Machinekeys folder**

Original permission for this folder can be found in [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278381). In my case I have changed permission for "Everyone", gave read permissions where it removed "Special permissions" tick. So I checked with one of my team member (Right click folder> Properties > Security > Advanced > select "Everyone" > Edit > Click "Advanced settings" in permission check box list

[image: Special permissions]

Hope this will save someone's day!

Here is where I found the answer [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/339ogk/this_certificate_issue_invalid_provider_type_has/), credit goes to him for documenting this.

Comment: Cheers big ears.

Comment: You're a life-saver! Just encountered this issue when deploying to an Amazon EC2 machine for the first time and was totally bewildered why my code suddenly started failing.

Comment: This fixed my issue. I only gave full control to the "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" user though, which is the user account under which the application pool that hosts my application is running.

Answer (score 17):

In my case, the following code worked fine in localhost (both NET 3.5 and NET 4.7):

```
 var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password);

 string xml = "....";
 XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
 xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

 SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDocument);
 signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;

 //etc...
```

But it failed when deployed to an Azure Web App, at `certificate.PrivateKey`

It worked by changing the code as follows:

```
 var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                                                                   //^ Here
 string xml = "....";
 XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
 xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);

 SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDocument);
 signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
                                      // ^ Here too

 //etc...
```

A whole day of work lost thanks to Microsoft Azure, once again in my life.

Comment: Thanks to your comment. I only wasted 3 hours and then stumbled on your comment. It saved my whole weekend

Comment: The GetRSAPrivateKey() was the critical bit for me

Comment: Adding `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable` worked for me on Azure

Comment: Today it failed in localhost with the same error but I fixed it by running Visual Studio "as administrator"

Comment: Had the same problem when implementing an API on IIS under Windows Server 2016. The first modification worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is it! Not sure what other solutions are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks Dude, missing some X509KeyStorageFlags is the main issue here

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me:
IIS / Application pool / Load User Profile = true

Comment: I had same issue but only with asp.net application in IIS. PrivateKey loaded fine in console application with same code but would fail when tried from asp.net application, low and behold LoadUserProfile was set to false on my app pool...this was a life saver thankyou!

Answer (score 9):

The link to [Alejandro's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20130727071113/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/12/22/invalid-provider-type-specified-error-when-accessing-x509certificate2-privatekey.aspx) is key.

I believe this is because the certificate is stored on your machine with the CNG ("Crypto Next-Generation") API.  The old .NET API is not compatible with it, so it doesn't work.

You can use the Security.Cryptography wrapper for this API ([available on Codeplex](https://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/)).  This adds extension methods to `X509Certificate/X509Certificate2`, so your code will look something like:

```
using Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates; // Get extension methods

X509Certificate cert; // Populate from somewhere else...
if (cert.HasCngKey())
{
    var privateKey = cert.GetCngPrivateKey();
}
else
{
    var privateKey = cert.PrivateKey;
}
```

Unfortunately the object model for CNG private keys is quite a bit different.  I'm not sure if you can export them to XML like in your original code sample...in my case I just needed to sign some data with the private key.

Comment: There is no .HasCngKey() method on my certificate class even though I have the using clause.

Comment: Something must be wrong.  Can you call it explicitly as `Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateExtensionMethods.HasCngKey(cert)`?

Comment: Is this still the way to go in the most recent .NET (4.6)?

Comment: @MichaelChan It is except `GetCngPrivateKey` has been renamed to `GetRSAPrivateKey`. I ran into this error with EncryptedXml, I discovered the code was updated in net462 to use this new method so no longer throws an error.

Answer (score 9):

As many other answers have pointed out, this issue arises when the private key is a Windows Cryptography: Next Generation (CNG) key instead of a "classic" Windows Cryptographic API (CAPI) key.

Beginning with .NET Framework 4.6 the private key (assuming it's an RSA key) can be accessed via an extension method on X509Certificate2: `cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()`.

When the private key is held by CNG the `GetRSAPrivateKey` extension method will return an `RSACng` object (new to the framework in 4.6).  Because CNG has a pass-through to read older CAPI software keys, `GetRSAPrivateKey` will usually return an `RSACng` even for a CAPI key; but if CNG can't load it (e.g. it's an HSM key with no CNG driver) then `GetRSAPrivateKey` will return an `RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

Note that the return type for `GetRSAPrivateKey` is `RSA`.  Beginning with .NET Framework v4.6 you shouldn't need to cast beyond `RSA` for standard operations; the only reason to use `RSACng` or `RSACryptoServiceProvider` is when you need to interop with programs or libraries that use the `NCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE` or the key identifier (or opening a persisted key by name).  (.NET Framework v4.6 had a lot of places that still cast the input object to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, but those were all eliminated by 4.6.2 (of course, that's more than 2 years ago at this point)).

ECDSA certificate support was added in 4.6.1 via a `GetECDsaPrivateKey` extension method, and DSA was upgraded in 4.6.2 via `GetDSAPrivateKey`.

On .NET Core the return value from `Get[Algorithm]PrivateKey` changes depending on the OS.  For RSA it's `RSACng`/`RSACryptoServiceProvider` on Windows, `RSAOpenSsl` on Linux (or any UNIX-like OS except macOS), and a non-public type on macOS (meaning you can't cast it beyond `RSA`).

Answer (score 4):

Using Visual Studio 2019 and IISExpress, I was able to correct this problem by removing the following flag when loading the `.pfx|.p12` file:

```
X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet
```

Before:

```
X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
```

After:

```
X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable
```

Normally, I'll load the cert this way:

```
var myCert = new X509Certificate2("mykey.pfx", "mypassword", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

This does NOT raise an Exception, instead the Exception is raised when attempting to use the certificate (or in my case, when trying to obtain the `.PrivateKey`).  I've found this issue can be caused when the [invoking user has insufficient permissions](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14745#issuecomment-276873818).

Since I rely on the `MachineKeySet` flag for some environments, my current solution is to swallow the Exception, change the flags, try again. :/

A more organic solution would be to test the permissions level and set this flag dynamically, however I'm not aware of a simple way to do this, hence the fallback.

**NOTE:** The `.pfx` file I'm using was created from a website that uses a JavaScript library (`digitalbazaar/forge`) which does NOT use CNG (Cryptography Next Generation) Key Storage Providers.  here are many common causes for this same error (the most common fixes related to `CNG` extensions, which have -- unfortunately even changed namespaces in .NET versions), which throw the same error.  Microsoft should ultimately be more verbose when throwing these types of errors.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue and after attempting the suggestions in this post without success. I was able to resolve my issue by reloading the certificate with the Digicert certificate utility https://www.digicert.com/util/. This allows one to select the provider to load the certificate into. In my case loading the certificate into the  **Microsoft RSA Schannel Cryptographic Provider** provider where I had expected it to be in the first place resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell version of the answer from @berend-engelbrecht, assuming `openssl` installed via [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/OpenSSL.Light)

```
function Fix-Certificates($certPasswordPlain)
{
    $certs = Get-ChildItem -path "*.pfx" -Exclude "*.converted.pfx"
    $certs | ForEach-Object{
        $certFile = $_

        $shortName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($certFile.Name)
        Write-Host "Importing $shortName"
        $finalPfx = "$shortName.converted.pfx"


        Set-Alias openssl "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe"

        # Extract public key
        OpenSSL pkcs12 -in $certFile.Fullname -nokeys -out "$shortName.cer" -passin "pass:$certPasswordPlain"

        # Extract private key
        OpenSSL pkcs12 -in $certFile.Fullname -nocerts -out "$shortName.pem" -passin "pass:$certPasswordPlain" -passout "pass:$certPasswordPlain"

        # Convert private key to RSA format
        OpenSSL rsa -inform PEM -in "$shortName.pem" -out "$shortName.rsa" -passin "pass:$certPasswordPlain" -passout "pass:$certPasswordPlain" 2>$null

        # Merge public keys with RSA private key to new PFX
        OpenSSL pkcs12 -export -in "$shortName.cer" -inkey "$shortName.rsa" -out $finalPfx -passin "pass:$certPasswordPlain" -passout "pass:$certPasswordPlain"

        # Clean up
        Remove-Item "$shortName.pem"
        Remove-Item "$shortName.cer"
        Remove-Item "$shortName.rsa"

        Write-Host "$finalPfx created"
    }
}

# Execute in cert folder
Fix-Certificates password
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in our IIS app:

```
 System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.PkcsUtils.CreateSignerEncodeInfo(CmsSigner signer, Boolean silent)
    System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.Sign(CmsSigner signer, Boolean silent)
    System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms.ComputeSignature(CmsSigner signer, Boolean silent)
```

Regenerating certs as mentioned here didnt help.
I also noticed that test console app works fine under pool user.

Problem disappeared after clearing "Enable 32-bit Applications" setting for IIS app pool.

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything in this post, but for me the solution was:

1. Import the original .p12 file into my local machine
2. Export it as a .pfx file checking the "Export all extended properties" and "Include all the certificates in the certification path if its possible" options
3. Read the new certificate using this flag options from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345262/an-internal-error-occurred-when-loading-pfx-file-with-x509certificate2) solution:

   ```
   var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certKeyFilePath, passCode,
   X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |       
   X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet );
   ```

Comment: in my case I did a simple export with the private key without extended properties or any includes and it worked without code modifications

Answer (score 1):

For a .net 4.8 WCF service I was getting this error because i hadn't (also) set the httpRuntime version.

Without the httpRuntime set i was getting the error whenever a secured .net tcp binding was present.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
    <!--<customErrors mode="Off" />-->
</system.web>
```

I had already setup the required permissions in mmc.exe -> add snap-in -> certificates -> personal -> all tasks -> manage private keys -> add [computer name]\IIS_IUSRS (all my application pools are ApplicationPoolIdentity [default] - which is covered by IIS_IUSRS)

Comment: same for me; net472 for a WCF service; adding httpRuntime 472 or 48 solved the problem. but strange, i can't use the findprivatekey tool on this certificate and if i try to change the rights on the pk files as administrator, i got an error on the enum and no read acces on one file !!

Answer (score 1):

the **PrivateKey and PublicKey properties are outdated** beginning with NET 4.6. Please use:

- cert.**GetRSAPrivateKey**() or **GetECDsaPrivateKey**()
- cert.**GetRSAPublicKey**() or **GetECDsaPublicKey**()

Regards

Answer (score 1):

After following the accepted answer (specifying KeySpec), the exception changed to `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.`. I resolved that exception by giving my web application access to the private key (IIS_IUSRS). I discovered that this would also fix the problem with my original certificate. So before generating and deploying new certificates, check the private key's permissions as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code is not able to read the PFX file. 
convert the pfx file to RSA format by doing the below steps.

Get the certificate and extract the pfx file from the certificate.

use the password 123456 below to have a quick solution.

rename your pfx to 'my.pfx' file to make it simple and put it in "C:\Certi"
make sure you have open SSL installed already in the system.
open cmd in windows system and type -->  OpenSSL
Stay cool and just run these ones by one  --> copy paste.
*Note

> -**passin**  is your Pfx file password 
>   -**passout** is the new password for converted pfx.

```
1. pkcs12 -in "C:\Certi\my.pfx" -nokeys -out "C:\Certi\MYCERT.cer" -passin "pass:123456"

2. pkcs12 -in "C:\Certi\my.pfx" -nocerts –out “C:\Certi\MYCERT.pem" -passin "pass:123456" -passout "pass:123456"

3. rsa -inform PEM -in "C:\Certi\MYCERT.pem" -out "C:\Certi\MYCERT.rsa" -passin "pass:123456" -passout "pass:123456"
```

if you face issue in the 3rd command go here https://decoder.link/converter
Click PKC#12 To PEM 
upload your pfx file and get it converted online. 
download the zip file. 
it contains 3 files. just copy ".key" file and rename it as my.key and put in "C:\Certi"

```
4. rsa -in C:\Certi\my.key -out C:\Certi\domain-rsa.key

5. pkcs12 -export -in "C:\Certi\MYCERT.cer" -inkey "C:\Certi\domain-rsa.key" -out "C:\Certi\CONVERTED.pfx" -passin "pass:123456" -passout "pass:123456"


**Also, you can try below things if the issue still persists**
```

- Given access to app pool or IIS user to folder "mandatory to do"

Path --- > C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

- Delete the old keys (clear up the mess)
  Path  --- >  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

Answer (score 0):

This error went away after i removed the certificate from the store and imported it again from the .pfx file, using the Certificate Import Wizard (double-click the .pfx file) and an extra import option.

After checking the import option (same step where password is entered):

> "Mark this key as exportable. This will allow you to back up or transport your keys at a later time."

The privatekey could now be accessed from code without any errors.

I also explicitly select the "Personal" store on the 2nd to last step, but I don't think this matters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems on Windows 10, if I run my program without administrative privileges (whether I use the PrivateKey property or the GetRSAPrivateKey() extension method), I will see this exception (see the title of this discussion thread for the exception). If I run my program with administrative privileges and use the PrivateKey property, I will also see this exception. Only if I run my program with administrative privileges and use the GetRSAPrivateKey() extension method, I will not see this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue, I changed the '.jks' to '.pfx' without typing the password, once I changed the key store type again with the password it is worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing this issue on some computers in a security-critical environment, I found that, contrary to several answers, updating the Cryptographic Service Provider (CSP) of the certificate from the old CAPI standard to the new CNG standard resolved this issue.

The security policies probably restricted the use of CSPs relying on [deprecated cryptographic algorithms](https://www.pkisolutions.com/understanding-microsoft-crypto-providers/).

Updating the CSP to *Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider* based on [these instructions](https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/1578/SHA256-and-Converting-the-Cryptographic-Service-Provider-Type) fixed the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very strange issue regarding an imported PFX from OpenSSL on a Linux System and the ADWS (Active Directory Web Service).

When using the Import Certificate GUI through the MMC Snap Ins, the certificate was imported successfully and ADWS could find it and load.

When using this command with Powershell, the certificate appeared to have been imported successfully but ADWS was giving an Event ID 1402 error.

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dc01.test.pfx `
   -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password123!' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

```
Active Directory Web Services was unable to process the server certificate.  A certificate is required to use SSL/TLS connections. To use SSL/TLS connections, verify that a valid server authentication certificate from a trusted Certificate Authority (CA) is installed on the machine.
```

Enabling the debugging this was the culprit:

```
ADWSHostFactory: [04/01/2023 21:55:59] [6] ProvisionCertificate: caught a CryptographicException: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
   at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.WebServices.ADWSHostFactory.ProvisionCertificate(ServiceHost host)
```

I was stumped and tried some of the other solutions here but nothing worked.

Fortunately I discovered this guide from Component Space (https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/1578/SHA256-and-Converting-the-Cryptographic-Service-Provider-Type) which mentions the Cryptographic Provider being the issue as do a lot of others on this issue.

I could not see a way of changing this with powershell, but you can do this with certutil.

```
   certutil.exe -p 'Password123!' -csp "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -importPFX C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\dc01.test.pfx
```

The certificate now works as if I had added it via the GUI.

What I can't understand is why Powershell is adding it with a different cryptographic provider than if I add it through the MMC GUI.  I hope this helps some one else with a really weird and annoying bug.