# Error getting X509Certificate2.PrivateKey in Azure AppService

Tags: c#, azure, certificate, x509certificate

Few hours ago, I thought it was an [RSACryptoServiceProvider casting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638759/error-parsing-x509certificate2-privatekey-to-rsacryptoserviceprovider?noredirect=1#comment92211199_52638759).

But I attach the debuger to Azure AppService WebSite and I found out that the PrivateKey has an issue:

[image: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.]

And if run the same certificate, but in localhost private key works well:
[image]

Exception Detail, when I tried to get certificate.PrivateKey property:
    `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.
    at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
    at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()`

And when I tried certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey() method:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)
```

The way I initialize the Certificate is this one:

```
public X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(byte[] pBytes,string pPassword)
{
        X509Certificate2 vCertificate = null;
        try
        {
            vCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pBytes,pPassword);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex
        }
        return vCertificate
}
```

.Net Version Framework is v4.7

So should I need to configure something in the Azure configuration?
Any clue?

Dont think this is a duplicate of:  ["Invalid provider type specified" CryptographicException when trying to load private key of certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581811/invalid-provider-type-specified-cryptographicexception-when-trying-to-load-pri)

It looks like is a Azure restriction, configuration or something like that.

Comment: I think you wont have access to that WinAPi due to how Web Apps are architected.

Comment: You need to use cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581811/invalid-provider-type-specified-cryptographicexception-when-trying-to-load-pri/52654804#52654804)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Invalid provider type specified" CryptographicException when trying to load private key of certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581811/invalid-provider-type-specified-cryptographicexception-when-trying-to-load-pri)

Comment: using cert.GetRSAPrivateKey(), I got the same error : System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Invalid provider type specified

Comment: @Arquitecto That's definitely not expected.  If you're getting an exception from GetRSAPrivateKey please share the code you have and an exception stacktrace.

Comment: @bartonjs I updated the post. Is a very weird behavior, Im thinking to change the server service type to see what happens.

Comment: I changed from Azure to smarterasp.net as a hosting provider and the error is gone. Definetly is an Azure configuration error. I hope no one need to pass thought this, an entire waste of time.

Comment: Fuck Azure. I have the same issue and I didn't 6 months ago. @Arquitecto

Comment: @bartonjs - I have the same problem on Azure, the same code perfectly works fine on my machine, but it doesn't work on Azure App service.