# Accessing a local secure WCF Service returning error HTTP Error 403.16 - Forbidden

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have a WCF Service and a client application that connects to the service.

The WCF Service is hosted locally in IIS 10. The WCF Service is using HTTPS. The client application is running locally as well.

The error i receive is:
**HTTP Error 403.16 - Forbidden
Your client certificate is either not trusted or is invalid.
The client certificate used for this request is not trusted by the Web server.**

This error occurred after i attempted to view the service in the web browser.

**Questions**

1. How do i make it trusted by the Web Server?
2. Do i need to make any changes to the Server config and client config?
3. Do i need to make any changes in IIS 10?
4. Is the issue with how i created the certificates?

Here are the steps i took so far to try and get it working:

5. I created the Service Certificate and Client certificates on local machine using the following commands via Powershell:

   New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName
   "WcfServerTestCert" -FriendlyName "WcfServerTestCert" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)

   New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName "WcClientTestCert" -FriendlyName "WcfClientTestCert" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(10)

I used the following to assist me with the above [How to create self-signed certificates in Windows 10](https://www.oshyn.com/blogs/2017/november/how-to-create-self-signed-certificates-in-windows-10)

When i ran MMC, the certificates were added to the Personal store under Local Machine.

6. I also put the WCFServerTestCert in the Trusted Root Certification
   Authorities.
7. I then set the "https" binding with port 443 (default) in IIS and provided it
   the WCFServerTestCert from the "SSL certificate" list.
8. Set the SSL Settings to "require SSL" and selected "Accept"
9. Restarted the application pool and application

Here is the config for the Web Service/Server:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
<services>
    <service name="XXX.Zoo.WebServices.ZooServices_3_0" 
  behaviorConfiguration="ZooServices_3_0_Behavior">
        <endpoint
            address="https://localhost/Zootest_3_0/ZooServices_3_0.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="ZooServices_3_0_Binding"
            contract="XXX.Zoo.WebServices.IZooServices_3_0" />
        <endpoint

      address="https://localhost/Zootest_3_0/ZooServices_3_0.svc/mex"
            binding="mexHttpsBinding"
            contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
    </services>
   <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ZooServices_3_0_Binding"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" >
            <readerQuotas
                maxDepth="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483646"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
            <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" 
                 proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" 
          negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" 
          establishSecurityContext="true" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
    <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ZooServices_3_0_Behavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" 
       httpsGetUrl="https://localhost/Zootest_3_0/ZooServices_3_0.svc" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
            <!--The serviceCredentials behavior defines a service 
              certificate which is used by the service to authenticate 
          itself to  its clients and to provide message protection. -->
            <serviceCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate
                    findValue="WcfServerTestCert"
                    storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                    storeName="My"
                    x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
                <clientCertificate>
                    <authentication 
                  certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"/>
                </clientCertificate>
            </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
             </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>        
      </system.serviceModel>
   </configuration>
```

Here is the Web Config for the client. The client application config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
    <!--   User application and configured property settings go here.-->
    <!--   Example: <add key="settingName" value="settingValue"/> -->
    <add key="txtMessageXml.AutoSize" value="True" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
</appSettings>

<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
</startup>
        
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
        <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://localhost/zootest_3_0/ZooServices_3_0.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IZooServices_3_0"
            contract="ZooServices_3_0.IZooServices_3_0" name="WSHttpBinding_IZooServices_3_0" behaviorConfiguration="ZooServices_3_0_Behavior" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IZooServices_3_0">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ZooServices_3_0_Behavior">
                <!-- The clientCredentials behavior defines a certificate to present to a service
                     which is used by the client to authenticate itself to the service and provide
                     message integrity. -->
                <clientCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate findValue="WcfClientTestCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"/>
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: See if following from msdn helps : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942061/error-message-when-you-visit-a-web-site-that-is-hosted-on-iis-7-0-http

Comment: In "internet options" i had to add the following to Personal Store:
WcfServerTestCert
WcfClientTestCert

Removed WcfClientTestCert from "Trusted Root"

In Personal the following exists: WcfServerTestCert and WcfClientTestCert

In Trusted People the following exists
WcfClientTestCert

When i navigated to the service it prompted me for authentication. 
I then selected WcfClientTestCert and it let me through

However When i use my client application i now get the error:
"Invalid provider type specified."

Do you know why am i getting this error? The service reference was updated.

Comment: See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581811/invalid-provider-type-specified-cryptographicexception-when-trying-to-load-pri

Comment: Do i need to do this conversion for both my WcfServerTestCert and WcfClientTestCert?

Comment: The certificate is sent in the XML data from Client to Server so the server doesn't need the certificate.

Comment: Can you explain which certificate does the server not require please?

Comment: I did not say server did require certificate.  I said the client sends the certificate to the server in the xml file that is sent in the request.

Comment: how to install the certificate in order to be trusted by server, please refer to the following link.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb193bb4-0ffc-487d-8061-5e0bf1ae5721/wcf-and-nettcp-security-with-certificate?forum=wcf

Comment: The service is partially working in IIS 10. i don't get the certificate error and it  shows a "padlock" "certificate is valid" as i expected.

But when i try and access the service it still says "Client Certificate is invalid". The client certificate was created using the same Root CA used to create the Server Certificate. I checked Local Machine > Personal and the client certificate is valid. Am I still missing something? 

The certificates were recreated using PowerShell > New-SelfSignedCertificate approach.

Comment: when invoking the service on client side, try to add the following code snippets.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;           client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
    new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
    {
        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
        RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
    };