# An exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException': keyset does not exist

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa, x509certificate

All the steps made at this link  [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: keyset does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106011/system-security-cryptography-cryptographicexception-keyset-does-not-exist)

But it did not help to correct the error.

```
static public string Build64(string idOrder, double Amount) {

        string StrForSign = KKBRequestStr.Replace("%ORDER%", idOrder).Replace("%AMOUNT%", string.Format("{0:f}", Amount).Replace(",", "."));
        X509Certificate2 KKbCert = new X509Certificate2(KKBpfxFile, KKBpfxPass);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCSP = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)KKbCert.PublicKey.Key;
        byte[] SignData = rsaCSP.SignData(ConvertStringToByteArray(StrForSign), "SHA1"); // keyset does not exist!!!!!!!!
        Array.Reverse(SignData);
        string ResultStr = "<document>" + StrForSign + "<merchant_sign type=\"RSA\">" + Convert.ToBase64String(SignData, Base64FormattingOptions.None) + "</merchant_sign></document>";
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ConvertStringToByteArray(ResultStr), Base64FormattingOptions.None);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to contact Kazkom software engineers with your problem?

Comment: Net, ne svyazivalsya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you are trying to **sign** some data using RSA having only a **public** key.

RSA signing is a process of document verification. You sign a document using **private** key and then use **public** key to check if it is really yours. In other words, you cannot sign document with public key.

That's why you get error "keyset does not exist". Your keyset doesn't contain a private key for signing data.
You need to extract the private key from your `KkbCert` and use it for signing.

Comment: I extracted KKBpfxFile, Import successfully completed